# TabLayout and Toolbar are not moving up and down on scroll of listview inside view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have some design problem while using material controls in my application. I have scenario something like as toolbar,tablayout, and below tablayout there is View pager and each page contains fragment having listview implementation. I want to move tablayout to toolbar and hide toolbar on scrolling of listview and manage position of tablayout and toolbar according to listview scrolling.

Comment: can u please post your toolbar xml code linked by `<include layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar_keyline_insets" />`

Comment: @CollinsA i have include edit the XML with layout "toolbar_actionbar_keyline_insets" .